# Does AVG have any features that Lookout doesn't have, or vice versa?

Tags: antivirus

I'm trying to decide which antivirus/malware protection I should use on my android phone.

It looks like the best options are either [Lookout](https://www.mylookout.com/) or [AVG](http://www.avg.com/us-en/antivirus-for-android).  Where can I find a list of features that the one has and the other doesn't, or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

[Lookout](https://www.mylookout.com/)

**Free**

- **Security**

  - Anti-Virus, Anti-Malware, Anti-Spyware
- **Backup**

  - Contacts Backup
  - Restore Data to Existing Phone
- **Missing Device**

  - Find Phone (Locate & Scream)
- **Support**

  - Standard Support

**Paid** *($2.99/Month or $29.99/year)*

- **Security**

  - Block phishing and malicious websites
  - Protect your privacy with Privacy Advisor
- **Backup**

  - Photo, Call History Backup
  - Transfer Data to New Phone
- **Missing Device**

  - Remote Wipe
  - Remote Lock
- **Support**

  - Premium Support

---

[AVG](http://www.avg.com/us-en/antivirus-for-android)

**Free**

- **Security**

  - Scan whole device and identify and remove viruses with a simple click
  - Automatic scans can be run weekly, daily, or on demand
  - Check apps for malware before downloading from app stores
  - Check web content, emails, and SMS for malware before downloading to device
- **Theft protection**

  - Locate lost or stolen device using GPS
  - Create and display onscreen message remotely
  - Lock device and wipe content
  - Manage applications remotely
- **SMS spam protection**

  - Basic protection from SMS spammers

**Paid** *($9.99 One time charge ???)*

- **Premium SMS security**

  - All text messages checked for malicious content and spam in real time
  - Text message spam blocked at source
- **VIP support**

  - Anti-Virus PRO customers receive premium level support whenever they need it
- **No disruption**

  - Anti-Virus PRO is free of advertising and other disruptions